# LQP-reviewers: Please don't leave multiple similar comments

Tags: discussion, comments, low-quality-posts

I don't want to say that posting the review-comments is wrong, but how about we choose "No comment needed" when there is already a good comment?

It's a great feature in the LQPRQ to leave one of the proposed comments when recommending deletion. But this occurs very often:

[image: example1]

Or here, where the review-comment doesn't add any useful information for the author of the post:

[image: example2]

It's just useless to post multiple similar comments. Usually one of these comments is enough to understand what is wrong with the post. If a user doesn't understand the first comment, he won't care about (or understand) the next default comments either. Also, I can imagine the author of a post with lots of review-comments getting either angry or disappointed when users are "spamming" comments on his post.

**Do we really need to pile review comments or can we teach user not to do?**

---

I don't want to blame the users that are posting these comments and the screenshots are just examples.

Comment: XY problem. People shouldn't be posting such *answers* in the first place.

Comment: @Glorfindel: The auto-comments are to teach answerers (those and others) not to do the same thing again. If the comments are obviously dumb, this hurts the goal of teaching. So by suggesting that the comments don't matter, you're apparently suggesting that there's no need for comments to be left on deleted answers at all, which I do not think is wise.

Comment: They *do* matter, and it's important that reviewers chose the right one. Still, I see only one out of five comments in the question above which is off the mark. The other ones may be *superfluous* but they aren't wrong, unlike the answers.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Sure, they're not *wrong*, just *dumb*. When people are very obviously not paying much attention to what else is being said, that seriously undermines credibility.

Answer (score 15):

If a user feels that an earlier reviewer used an inappropriate reason, we'd *want* them to choose a comment with what they feel is the appropriate reason.  Someone posting an invalid reason for deleting a post shouldn't prevent anyone else from posting a *correct* reason for deleting it, and doing so will better allow the author to address those problems.

If you feel the prior comments are No Longer Needed (NLN), then you can raise NLN moderator flag(s) on those comments, which will likely result in them being deleted, if the post is not deleted first. If you feel a comment is sufficiently bad such that it needs to be separately removed even if the post is deleted, then raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag *on the post* and explain the issue.

Comment: Yes. Of course it's good if someone posts "This does not really answer the question" on a link-only answer. But there are lot's of cases, where those comments are just redundant information.

Comment: @FelixSFD If you feel that certain options are redundant then propose those options be removed/changed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I did look at the examples in the question.

Comment: @Servy: But your answer talks only about "inappropriate" reasons, and only one of the examples show that even one person thought any preceding reason was at all inappropriate.

Comment: @NathanTuggy They apparently felt the need to use a different reason than someone else.  If they agreed with the other user's reason, and choose it, then only one comment would be posted, and there would be no issue.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, that works real well with manually-left comments, doesn't it?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Additionally, the point in the answer applies regardless of the examples provided; it's important that a reviewer be *able* to provide a comment for a different reason if they disagree.  If we tell people to never post a review comment when there is already a review comment, then that causes a problem, so clearly there are going to be cases where posing a 2nd review comment is the appropriate action, contrary to the question's assertion.

Comment: @Servy: "I don't want to say that posting the review-comments is wrong, but how about we choose "No comment needed" when there is **already a good comment**?" -- first line of question, emphasis added.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, people manually posting those kinds of comments (particularly when not tailored to the specific post) can indeed end up causing problems.

Comment: @Servy: Sorry, I'm feeling a bit grouchy because normally you're extremely thoughtful and it feels like you're just not living up to your usual meta attentiveness. In this case, the problem comes in leaving a tailored, unusually helpful comment… and then some dorks coming along with auto-comments that don't fit as well and that won't be suppressed by the existing manual comment as they would be by auto-comments. Blaming the manual comment is exactly the wrong way around, as that's really the best one!

Comment: @NathanTuggy Like I said, a comment specifically tailored to the post tends to not be problematic, it's the people using their own users scripts going around posting their own templated comments that I find largely problematic.  They miss out on many features that the review system is able to incorporate (most notably that the comment shows up even after the post is deleted, which is important for the user actually realizing that they did something wrong) and because those comments simply don't tend to add more than the review's boilerplates.

Comment: I don't see any comments in the examples shown that look like anyone actually wrote them, it's just non-review boilerplate vs review boilerplate.

Comment: Also note that until relatively recently, if users picked the exact same reason, it *would* leave an exact duplicate comment. This is no longer so.

Comment: @TinyGiant If by recently, you mean like 2 years ago...

Comment: @Servy no. The comments we can select are good. They are not exact duplicates, but it posting more than one of them doesn't make sense. (except in the case you described) Additionally, the comments many users post with the autocomment script usually provide a detalied explanation with links to the tour or suitable meta-posts. Review-comments after such a comment being superfluous doesn't mean they are useless. I like the review-comments. I just want to make people think before posting them.

Comment: *their own templated comments that I find largely problematic*, can you explain better since I taguht this was useful for OP and SO, in case of VLQ (link-only) it gives OP a chance to edit before LQP queue (and you can not be sure that review will pass comments), In case of NAA it helps OP to understand why post is deleted and hopefully they will avoid other similar posts (Note: most if not all NAA is deleted by mods most often with no review comment)

Comment: @PetterFriberg Mods don't touch a huge portion of NAA posts; the review queues are quite good at handling the them.  There's no *reason* for them to need to edit the post before it goes into the queue.  It's perfectly sufficient for the queue to add the comment.

Comment: @FelixSFD Why go out of your way to post a functionally duplicate comment, and then go out of your way to get someone else to *not* post a comment, when you could just let the queue do its job and post the review comment.  It does it better.  You're going out of your want to make other people go out of *their* way to provide less useful behavior, when you could just do none of that and everyone would be better off.

Comment: @servy yes that is what I meant by recently, but it was close to a year ago.

Comment: @Servy you are not correct, mods delete almost all NAA lately within 10-30 minutes, trust me I flag around 50 per day and can see when and who deleted it.

Comment: You can check the destiny of some (10.000) NAA/VLQ post [here](http://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts) the one's with checkmark where marked by users as true positives and flagged